# Are there any RedBeanPHP ORM analogs in Java?

Tags: java, orm, redbean

I'm looking for the simplest Java ORM with "freeze"-like capabilities.
Are there any tools such where I don't have to mess with all those JPA/Hibernate xml config files?
I need to make changes in the schema of my model in production.

Comment: JPA doesn't require XML mapping files. (It will require one config file to point it at your database and set up the provider.) Hibernate, which can be used as a JPA provider, also supports automatically updating a schema when it's initialised.

Answer (score 1):

This guy started a Java edition of RedBeanPHP, it was called RedBean4J but it no longer exists. Maybe you can contact him and ask for the code?

http://code.google.com/u/danil.kornishev@gmail.com/updates/projects